# Angular route won't load templateUrl

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, angularjs-routing, angular-template

I can't seem to load the templateUrl using the angularjs routing.
Using django and angularjs.
What I do is go to *127.0.0.1:8000/phones/*, it redirects me to *127.0.0.1:8000/phones/#/*

Then, I refresh, to double check.
In both cases (first time and after refresh) I just see the TESTING string. Here's the code:

**index.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js">        </script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var phones = angular.module('phones', ['ngRoute']);
            phones.config(function($interpolateProvider){
                $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
                $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
            });
            phones.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                    when('/', {
                        templateUrl: "{% static "partials/first.html" %}",
                    }).otherwise({
                        redirectTo: "/"
                    });
            }]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="phones">
        <div ng-view></div>
        TESTING
    </body>
</html>
```

**first.html**

```
HELLO
```

From the runserver console:

```
[31/Jul/2014 18:40:46] "GET /phones/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1488
[31/Jul/2014 18:40:48] "GET /phones/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1488
[31/Jul/2014 18:40:48] "GET /static/partials/first.html HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

As you can see, the angularjs routing does requests the HTML , but still it doesn't get displayed.

Another question I have is regarding the console output.
Why does it send (or just show) the GET request for first.html only when I refresh?
I'm expecting the routing to request the first.html on first time..

**EDIT**
Adding the browser's console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at v (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.min.js:6:357)
    at g.$broadcast (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:102:324)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.min.js:11:179
    at C (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:91:121)
    at C (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:91:121)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:92:288
    at g.$eval     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:100:198)
    at g.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:98:82)
    at g.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:101:12)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:66:321) angular.js:9037
```

**EDIT #2** - adding browser's console after changing to the not minify angular:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at update (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.js:871:25)
    at Scope.$broadcast (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js:11803:28)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.js:552:26
    at wrappedCallback (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js:10549:81)
    at wrappedCallback (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js:10549:81)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js:10635:26
    at Scope.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js:11528:28)
    at Scope.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js:11373:31)
    at Scope.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js:11634:24)
    at done (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js:7635:45)
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: The `#/` is added automatically by Angular's `routeProvider` when you set `html5mode(false)`, which is the default. Are you getting any error from the browser console?

Comment: Added the browser's console after the EDIT. And regarding the hashtag, I know that, but why does my runserver consol show the GET request only upon the refresh?

Comment: Try including non-minified versions for debugging and see where that console error takes you. Also, if you ever want to minify your app, you'll want to change `phones.config(function($interpolateProvider){` to `phones.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider){`

Comment: @kiswa, As you can see from the 2nd edit, it got me the same thing. I really can't figure out why this simple thing is not working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including the wrong version of AngularJS.

Change this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js">        </script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js">        </script>
```

That took way too long to figure out!